# windows phone equivalent of ondestroy() of android

Tags: windows-phone

I am new in WP platform. I want to do some operation when user leaves the current page.Where can I write the codes of the operations.Like ondestroy method of android.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you are interested in developing to Windows Phone OS.
Please check this link to examine WP Application Lifecycle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

To answer your direct question: You should override the OnNavigatedFrom function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yo can do something overriding "OnNavigatedFrom" and using `this.Frame.BackStack.Last()` to compare with the current page to know if you go back or not.